# Erro "Internal Server Error" no servidor localhost:3000 ao utilizar o comando npm run dev

Tags: localhost, next.js

Estou estudando NextJS e utilizei o comando npm create-next-app para criar um template do next, porém quando utilizo o comando npm run dev, que deveria abrir a aplicação na porta 3000, o localhost:3000 retorna "Internal Server Error", e o terminal retorna uma série de erros.

Erros no terminal:

```
warn  - C:/Users/familia/Desktop/Guilherme/Projetos/NLW5/podcastrnext/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers: * C:\Users\familia\Desktop\Guilherme\Projetos\NLW5\podcastrnext\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\interopRequireDefault.js
    Used by 4 module(s), i. e.
C:\Users\familia\Desktop\Guilherme\Projetos\NLW5\podcastrnext\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!C:\Users\familia\Desktop\Guilherme\Projetos\NLW5\podcastrnext\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!C:\Users\familia\Desktop\Guilherme\Projetos\NLW5\podcastrnext\node_modules\next\dist\client\router.js * C:\users\familia\desktop\guilherme\projetos\nlw5\podcastrnext\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\interopRequireDefault.js
    Used by 10 module(s), i. e.
C:\Users\familia\Desktop\Guilherme\Projetos\NLW5\podcastrnext\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!C:\Users\familia\Desktop\Guilherme\Projetos\NLW5\podcastrnext\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!C:\users\familia\desktop\guilherme\projetos\nlw5\podcastrnext\node_modules\next\dist\client\dev\amp-dev.js

C:/Users/familia/Desktop/Guilherme/Projetos/NLW5/podcastrnext/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireWildcard.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers: * C:\Users\familia\Desktop\Guilherme\Projetos\NLW5\podcastrnext\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\interopRequireWildcard.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
C:\Users\familia\Desktop\Guilherme\Projetos\NLW5\podcastrnext\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!C:\Users\familia\Desktop\Guilherme\Projetos\NLW5\podcastrnext\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!C:\Users\familia\Desktop\Guilherme\Projetos\NLW5\podcastrnext\node_modules\next\dist\client\router.js * C:\users\familia\desktop\guilherme\projetos\nlw5\podcastrnext\node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\interopRequireWildcard.js
    Used by 8 module(s), i. e.
C:\Users\familia\Desktop\Guilherme\Projetos\NLW5\podcastrnext\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js!C:\Users\familia\Desktop\Guilherme\Projetos\NLW5\podcastrnext\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-babel-loader.js??ref--4-1!C:\users\familia\desktop\guilherme\projetos\nlw5\podcastrnext\node_modules\next\dist\client\next-dev.js

C:/Users/familia/Desktop/Guilherme/Projetos/NLW5/podcastrnext/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/typeof.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
```

Comment: Apague a node_modules e execute o npm install novamente

Comment: Fiz isso e não resolveu

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Error: There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing

Esse problema normalmente ocorre no windows, quando você está com o terminal apontando para o arquivo e alguma parte do caminho difere do original para o arquivo exatamente, inclusive entre letras maiúsculas e minúsculas. Para resolver isso é bem simples:

Basta reabrir o seu VSCode (caso tenha sido através do code .) novamente passando exatamente o caminho do arquivo, cuidando muito bem o nome de cada pasta para chegar até o projeto. Cada letra seja maiúscula ou minúscula precisa ser igual, o caminho todo até o projeto.
Em outras situações/erros que não só a abertura do projeto no VSCode, a solução também é válida.

Você pode também abrir pelo CMD diretamente, que aparentemente não ocorre o erro.(editado)

Funcionou pra mim, talvez seja o mesmo problema.

Comment: Pelo CMD funcionou, muito obrigado

Answer (score -2):

Existe uma probabilidade de você estar fazendo Import do Módulo do Next de forma errada.

Verifique os Imports da aplicação com se está com Letra maiscula ou letra mininuscula.

O Npm está indicando que tem multiplas chamadas de Import com o mesmo nome apenas sendo diferenciado pelo a letra minuscula ou maiuscula no caso Casing

Ou seja, você está importando módulos com nomes iguais apenas alterando entre maiscula ou minuscula o que está causando o erro.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada, mas mesmo rodando o template do next, da esse erro

Comment: O erro só aparece utilizando o PowerShell, consegui resolver com o CMD, obrigado pela ajuda